# IOS swift изменить язык

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Такая задача требуется сделать функцию выбора языка внутри приложение. Как в swift программно изменить локализацию?

Comment: Стоит заметить, что в iOS 13 локализацию любого приложения можно сменить через системные настройки, и реализовывать эту функциональность в самом приложении бессмысленно (если только вы не поддерживаете более ранние оси).

Comment: Согласен с @DmitrySerov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
extension Bundle {
    static var localizedBundle: Bundle {
        let languageCode = foo.current
        if languageCode == .sys {
            return Bundle.main
        }
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: languageCode.rawValue, ofType: "lproj") else {
            return Bundle.main
        }
        return Bundle(path: path) ?? .main
    }
}

func NSLocalizedString(_ key: String, comment: String) -> String {
    return Bundle.localizedBundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: nil)
}
```

И потом использовать NSLocalizedString(key:comment:), как обычно.

Comment: Этот код я должен разместить куда?

Comment: Создайте любой файл, например, Utility.swift. положите туда. Почитайте, как используется NSLocalizedString().

Comment: Это костыль, так лучше не делать, а использовать штатный вариант - через настройки системы. Причем, по умолчанию, у пользователя будет использоваться язык, выбранный в системе (если есть такая локализация).

Comment: Это способ изменения языка приложения на отличный от установленного в системе.